# Finding sequences of 0's in a 2D binary grid

Tags: algorithms, arrays

*Requirements:*

> Given a 2D array of 1's and 0's (black and white cells) find blocks of white cells of size 1xT or Tx1 where T >= 1. Any block should not be a subset of a larger block.
> **Return the number of these blocks.**

[image: An example of a solved grid]

This is an example solution of a 5x3 grid. There should be 8 blocks. Block `y:1, x:0` is not a block because it would be a subset of a bigger block `y:1->3, x:0`.

**What I've tried so far**

I've developed a pretty inefficient solution where I iterate through all white cells and for each one get a vertical and horizontal block. Then only accept either block if it isn't a subset of an already accepted block.

The most time complex operation in my code is checking whether a block is a subset of another accepted block.

**My questions**

What would be a more efficient solution to this problem?

Is there a data structure that would help me with this?

Comment: Do you want to find the minimum number of blocks? In that case, in your example case, $8$ blocks are not minimum.

Comment: Is $T$ an input?

Comment: (The most interesting part is blocks of size 1 having no direction.)

Comment: Maximum number of blocks, not minimum. **T** is not an input. Direction doesn't matter so blocks of size 1 can be in row or column direction.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve it easily in O(mn). where `m*n` is matrix dimension.
first consider only `1*T` type blocks.

iterate each row and in any row whenever you see a 0->1 consecutive element increase your block count by 1. (if first element of row is 1 then also increase count)
similarly, do this on columns.

(here don't consider `1*1` blocks initially in any iteration. finally after iterating over all rows and columns. check for `1*1` blocks separately)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something this only works for a few problems. Here's an example of an incorrect solution with this algorithm: https://i.imgur.com/hb5a9Zc.jpg
Red is correct solution (5), blue is your algorithm.

Comment: count only when you go from 0->1 not 1->0.

Comment: in your example this algo works fine

Comment: Your algorithm only works for the one example I provided, but with a few modifications it does work for all of my test cases as well.

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see any difficulty in this exercise.

Scan every row in turn, in any order. In a row, scan every column from left to right (or conversely), start a block and increment the counter when you meet a white, and end the block when you meet a black or the end of the row.

Scan every column in turn, in any order. In a column, scan every row from top to bottom (or conversely), start a block and increment the counter when you meet a white, and end the block when you meet a black or the end of the column.

Comment: Does this solve the "any block should not be a subset of a larger block"? I don't think it does, because it would also find the y1,x0 block in my example.

Comment: @Vid: it has to find it as an horizontal block. Or your explanations are unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with both the suggestions by [Yves Daoust](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/157050/161407) and [Ashish gupta](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/147999/161407). The following observations should hold:

- A $1 \times S$ block can only be a subset of a $T \times 1$ block if $ S = 1 $.
- An $S \times 1$ block can only be a subset of a $1 \times T$ block if $ S = 1 $.
- Only isolated $ 1 \times 1 $ blocks (without white neighbors) are not subsets of a larger blocks.
- $ 1 \times T $ blocks in different rows can never be subsets of one another.
- $ T \times 1 $ blocks in different columns can never be subsets of one another.

This should allow You to split the block finding as follows:

1. Find $ 1 \times T $ blocks for $ T > 1 $ in each row separately
2. Find $ T \times 1 $ blocks for $ T > 1 $ in each column separately
3. Find all isolated $ 1 \times 1 $ blocks

Both `1.` and `2.` can both be reduced to the same 1D problem. The following Python code finds all white segments longer than 1 in a 1D array:

```python
import numpy as np


def find_segments( array_1d ):
  array_1d = np.asarray(array_1d, dtype=bool)
  assert array_1d.ndim == 1

  # append black block for simplicity
  # (otherwise last segment needs separate handling)
  array_1d = np.append(array_1d, 1)

  start = None

  for i,ai in enumerate(array_1d):
    if start is None and ai == 0:
      # segment start found
      start = i

    if start is not None and ai == 1:
      # segment end found
      end = i-1
      if start < end: # <- only accept segments greater than 1 
        yield (start,end) 
      start = None

    i += 1
```

Finding isolated $ 1 \times 1 $ blocks should be as simple as going through each blocks and looking at its neighbors:

```python
def find_1x1_blocks( array_2d ):
  array_2d = np.asarray(array_2d, dtype=bool)
  assert array_2d.ndim == 2

  # pad with black for simplicity
  array_2d = np.pad(array_2d, 1, constant_values=1)

  for (i,j),aij in np.ndenumerate(array_2d):
    if(
      aij == 0
      and array_2d[i-1,j  ] == 1 # <- North 
      and array_2d[i,  j+1] == 1 # <- East
      and array_2d[i+1,j  ] == 1 # <- South
      and array_2d[i,  j-1] == 1 # <- West
    ):
      # subtract padding
      i -= 1
      j -= 1
      yield (i,j)
```

Using these two subroutines together, we should be able to find all blocks without duplicates:

```python
def find_all_blocks( array_2d ):  
  array_2d = np.asarray(array_2d, dtype=bool)
  assert array_2d.ndim == 2

  (m,n) = array_2d.shape

  # search rows
  for i in range(m):
    for (j,k) in find_segments(array_2d[i,:]):
      yield { 'y': i, 'x': (j,k) }

  # search columns
  for k in range(n):
    for (i,j) in find_segments(array_2d[:,k]):
      yield { 'y': (i,j), 'x': k }

  # collect 1x1 blocks
  for (i,j) in find_1x1_blocks(array_2d):
    yield { 'y': i, 'x': j }
```

All that's left now is to count the blocks. Let's use Your example:

```python
input = np.array(
  [[1,0,0],
   [0,1,0],
   [0,0,1],
   [0,0,0],
   [1,0,0]]
)

blocks = [*find_all_blocks(input)]

for block in blocks:
  print(block)
# Output:
# {'y': 0, 'x': (1, 2)}
# {'y': 2, 'x': (0, 1)}
# {'y': 3, 'x': (0, 2)}
# {'y': 4, 'x': (1, 2)}
# {'y': (1, 3), 'x': 0}
# {'y': (2, 4), 'x': 1}
# {'y': (0, 1), 'x': 2}
# {'y': (3, 4), 'x': 2}

print(len(blocks))
# Output: 8
```